# .Net Compression and SQL Server 2005 NVARCHAR(MAX)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, compression, nvarchar

Can I safely store a .Net compressed memory stream (System.IO.Compression) in an SQLServer 2005 NVARCHAR(MAX) field?  SQLServer 2008 is not an alternative.

Answer (score 4):

Use VARBINARY(MAX) for binary data - VARCHAR(MAX) and NVARCHAR(MAX) are for character-data (strings).

Comment: Argh - you beat me too it (+1 for you)

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off using `varbinary(max)`

Answer (score 1):

I would think varbinary(max) is more suitable. Remember that there is a max size of 2GB.

Answer (score 1):

A Stream is just a pointer to data, so you cannot store the stream into SQL Server, you can store the data that this stream points to. As you mention the `System.IO.Compression` namespace I suppose you mean either [DeflateStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx) or [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) which both contain binary data. The appropriate type to store binary data in SQL is `VARBINARY(MAX)`.